# Where do you put non-controller classes in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a class `Widgets`. Widgets are made up of `Doohickies`. I'm never going to need to access Doohickies directly via url -- they're essentially a private class, only used by Widgets. Where do you put your code to define the Doohicky class? In `/app/controllers/doohicky.php`? in `app/controllers/widget.php`? somewhere else? Obviously, the former seems cleaner, but it's not obvious to me how to make the Doohicky class available to Widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `Widgets` and `Doohickies` are probably [Models](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) in [MVC architecture](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html).

In which case, your paths would be:

```
app/models/widget.php
app/models/doohickies.php
```

Comment: Hmm... now I'm having second thoughts about not needing Doohicky to be a controller -- I do need two views of them -- one for output and one for the edit form. I just always feel reluctant to create a view file for what amounts to a single line of html. I'd rather just put it in a method of the model or something. But then I feel impure.

Comment: Neither controllers nor models should contain a single HTML tag. Only your views should know how to display your models.

Comment: If you don't want doohickies to be a view then use a simple helper, if that is not enough then a library.

Answer (score 0):

I see the question has been answered already, but there are a few things to bear to expand on it.

You could put widgets and doohickies in the `libraries` folder, if they are there to do a job rather than provide a data service.

Also, take a look at HMVC, which favours the idea that you can have mini-apps that look after various parts of your website (e.g. messages panels, search box/results, doohickies...). This  enables you to have smaller view partials dedicated to their widget controllers; and then the main controller calls in widgets but doesn't need knowledge of how they came about.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/